# Linux Angstrom can't start without serial cable plugged

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, angstrom, getty

I'm using the Altera Cyclone V Soc dev Kit and Linux Angstrom provides by rocketboards (http://rocketboards.org/foswiki/Documentation/GSRD141)
Kernel is : 3.10 LTSI

Linux can't start if any serial cable is not plugged.
I already removed getty which launched a login prompt at start up.

What should I change to enable linux to start properly ?
Have I to rebuild the kernel and change configuration ?

Comment: The only possible reason I can think of for this is only possible if the console port has hardware flow control, yet embedded boards almost always have serial ports without flow control (just Rx, Tx, and GND). If the serial port does have flow control, did you try shorting CTS ro RTS?

Comment: There is no hardware flow control on the board.

Comment: Nobody has come up with an answer over the weekend, so may I suggest some additional troubleshooting steps? Connect a one-way serial cable between the Angstrom board and the computer. Only 2 wires: GND and Tx from the Angstrom. Cut the Rx wire or disconnect it to guarantee that the Angstrom cannot possibly receive anything from the other end. Does it boot now? If the Angstrom sends any diagnostic messages you will be able to see them because Tx is still connected, while at the same time the remote computer cannot possibly influence the Angstrom's ability to boot because no Tx from there.

Comment: Thanks, I add that Rx LED on the board blinks when any cable is unplugged.